# Ruby error - Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, web

I am try to write a function that will find the items in an array which match the string passed to the function. See code below.

```
class Island 
  def filter(string) 
    for element in self
      if element.include? (string)
        yield(element)
      end
    end
  end 
end
list =    ["sasha","rory","rob","anthony","andre","tariq","kimberly","antoinette"]
list.filter("an"){|i| puts i}</i>
```

How i keep getting "undefined method 'filer' for #

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: you define method on `Island`, but call it on an array. What's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me object against the solution posted by @Sravan :

While it is true - and sometimes even a good solution - to monkey-patch a class, you have to be careful how to do it, because it may become a time bomb:

Ruby evolves, and new versions often add methods to existing classes. This means that if you add a method Array#search, and a new version of Ruby will also add a method of the same name, your new method will SILENTLY override the one in Ruby. You likely won't notice it for long time, until you are using a feature which is supposed to use Rubys Array#search - maybe by using something new in stdlib - and you get weird results. To track down this type of error can be a nightmare. This is exactly the case when you use *search* as a method name.

Now, how to do it then? Three possibilities:

(1) If you monkey-patch, use at least a method name which is unlikely to become part of the official interface. It might have your project's name as a prefix, or plenty of underscore characters, and so on. Note that this is not 100% foolproof: A later version of Ruby might add under the hood a private method with exactly the same name than the one you were choosing, but of course the odder your name, the less likely this will happen.

(2) If you don't like this idea of using "clumsy" names, you could at least test before defining the new method, whether it already exists, and throw an exception if it doesn't:

```
class Array
  if self.method_defined?(:search)
    raise "#{self.class}::search already defined"
  else
    def search(...)
     ...
    end
  end
end
```

(3) The third possibility is to avoid monkey-patching and keep the method in your Island class. In this case, the method definition would be different:

```
class Island
  def self.filter(array, string)
    ...
  end
end
```

and it would be called by

```
Island.filter(myarray, mystring)
```

UPDATE: Forgot a forth possibility:

(4) You can make Island a subclass of Array. I don't know what else you want to do with your islands, but maybe this is an option worth considering:

```
class Island < Array
  def filter(string)
    ...
  end
end
```

Of course, when invoking *filter*, you need to turn your array into an island, before you can use it:

```
list = Island.new([....])
```

Comment: This is the best solution, for sure. Try to just initialize your Island class with an Array instead of overriding Array itself.

Comment: This was a very good explanation of how to implement my class. I choose to use the 4th. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Following ruby's `convention over configuration`, you can add/overwrite any method in any class**

So, adding a function to array class makes it accessible to all the arrays. So, in this solution.

1) First thing is you have taken the **`filter`** function in **Island class**, instead, you need to take inside **`Array` class** since the list is an array.

```
    class Array 
      def filter(string) 
        for element in self
          if element.include? (string)
            yield(element)
          end
        end
      end 
    end

    list =    ["sasha","rory","rob","anthony","andre","tariq","kimberly","antoinette"]

   list.filter("an"){|i| puts i}

    O/P:
    anthony
    andre
    antoinette
```

2) Since **Filter** is a **keyword** as suggested by other answer, take another name for it. Eg: `search`

```
class Array 
     def search(string) 
        for element in self
          if element.include? (string)
            yield(element)
          end
        end
     end 
end

list.search("an"){|i| puts i}
```

Comment: Glad to help you. You can accept my answer. if it helped you. :)

Comment: "Since Filter is a keyword" – No, it's not. And even if it *were* a keyword, that's not a problem. You can name a method the same as a keyword. There are even such methods in the core libraries: `Object#class`, `Range#begin`, `Range#end`, `MatchData#begin`, `MatchData#end`, `Fiber::yield`, `Proc#yield`, `Enumerator::Yielder#yield`, `Enumerator#next`, `String#next`, `Integer#next`, `Symbol#next`.

Comment: @Jorg, thnx. yes, I know I can overwrite a method, but what if he needs to use his method and filter method both?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You said `filter` is a keyword and that therefore you need to change the name. Both of that is false: firstly, `filter` is *not* a keyword. Secondly, it is perfectly fine to name a method the same as a keyword. And thirdly, the OP already said that they are using your first option, i.e. the one with `filter` and are fine with it.

Comment: I agree, using the `filter` word even works. I am just saying that `Array` class already has a method named filter. I just told him that if would be better if you use any name other than that. Try, Another. Thats it.

Comment: I checked the documentation, and I couldn't find any mention of a method named `filter` in `Array` or anywhere else in Ruby 2.4.0, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.6, 2.2.5, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.9, 2.1.8, 2.1.7, 2.1.6, 2.1.5, 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.0, 1.9.3, 1.9.2, 1.9.1, 1.8.7, 1.8.6, as well as the current development version of Ruby 2.5.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, open ruby terminal, and type `Array.methods` and there you will find `filter` ,method. :)

Comment: First off: `Array.methods` is completely irrelevant, since that returns the methods you can call on the `Array` class, i.e. `Array`'s class methods. If you want the instance methods, you have to call `Array.instance_methods`. And secondly: `ruby -e 'p Array.methods.grep(/filter/) # []'`, `ruby -e 'p Array.instance_methods.grep(/filter/)' # []`. In fact: `ruby -e 'p ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).map(&:instance_methods).flatten.grep(/filter/)' # []`, so there is *no* method named `filter` defined in any module or class anywhere in Ruby.